# Adding User data to the JWT payload for spring security OAUth2

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am using a spring security OAuth2 using JWT tokens for some time but now I need to add 2 user defined values to the JWT token.

So when I added an additional set of parameters to the request /oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&user_value=1234567890.

The user_value above was for demonstrative purposes.  I can trace it all the way into my CustomTokenEnhancer (I connected this as a way to pass this information all the way through).  All the request parameters are visible through OAuth2Authentication authentication which is passed to my CustomTokenEnhancer.

Now I can add this information to the additional information which I see returned to me as part of the token request.  See below.

```
{
   "access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsicGhpLWFwaSJdLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIiwid3JpdGUiXSwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uIjoicGhpLXVzZXJtZ3RuIiwidXNlcl90b2tlbiI6IjEyMzQ1Njc4OTAiLCJleHAiOjE0ODczNjc2NzEsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfQ0xJRU5UIl0sImp0aSI6IjFlZDMzZTAxLTc1ZGUtNDNjZC1hMzk2LTFkMzk2N2Y1NDQ5OCIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InBoaS11c2VyIn0.p628BNaaGljypEcGXZMkstNeTN-221qzzNQQ0npxDLTszWaXkgXqsBnBbKf9XMEtWTeCQkIszC9ne1Ei2X5IWTskhLT9Rko-8K7Jq-mXUc6HJZW-3tGV5rRer8Eyyw1wysW9Jiyp7sPkN-TIx12A70f_LHm6PrRR4ECppHWADs-2DvYA30p8omT1_RTt2WlqC40mopUN2TBPkb1WulVpOUEpcP358Ox8oVP8VQRSkLGZKB_b0KZAK9KGjLg6WNh8RghZaBuYuJQpITe_0XEBs_JfwrHhcK1IGaoYwSS7IGp3Cima9OMljdzayDKRqlfSl3WhaBuFmD1S37p-OVQL0A",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":8967,
   "scope":"read write",
   "user_value":"1234567890",
   "jti":"1ed33e01-75de-43cd-a396-1d3967f54498"
}
```

But I don't want these values to be visible this way.  I want them to be added to the encrypted token.

I spent some time looking and it isn't clear how i actually add that.  This should be possible, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your own TokenEnhancer you have to encode it again:

```
@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    // Generate additional Information [...]


    // Write it to the token
    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken)accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(addInfo);

    // Encode Token to JWT
    String encoded = super.encode(accessToken, authentication);

    // Set JWT as value of the token
    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setValue(encoded);

    return accessToken;
}
```

You could solve this with the `JwtHelper` methods, but I just extended `JwtAccessTokenConverter`, so I could just use encode and decode.

When instantiating your Token enhancer, you have to add the keystore information:

```
private CustomTokenEnhancer jwtCustomEnhancer() {
    KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"), "***".toCharArray());
    CustomTokenEnhancer converter = new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("jwt"));

    return converter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar passing the value as a granted authority with help of user details service (not the token enhancer). At the client side, I wrote an extractor to retrieve the values from the principal injected by spring as type OAuth2Authentication. The following code is in Scala, but you may easily adapt to Java:

```html
/**
  * Mix-in to implicitly extract entity or identity from the principal.
  */
trait AuthorityExtractor {

  def _contextName(implicit principal: OAuth2Authentication) = id(principal, "CONTEXT_")

  def _entityId(implicit principal: OAuth2Authentication) = id(principal, "ENTITY_ID_")

  def _userId(implicit principal: OAuth2Authentication) = id(principal, "USER_ID_")

  def _identityId(implicit principal: OAuth2Authentication) = id(principal, "SELF_ID_")

  private def id(principal: OAuth2Authentication, prefix: String) = {
    import collection.JavaConversions._
    principal
      .getAuthorities
      .filter(_.toString.startsWith(prefix))
      .map(_.toString.substring(prefix.length))
      .headOption.getOrElse("")
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I extend `JwtAccessTokenConverter` class like that:

```
public class FooJwtAccessTokenConverter extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {
  @Override
  public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
     DefaultOAuth2AccessToken fooAccessToken = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(accessToken);
     fooAccessToken.getAdditionalInformation().put("foo_property", "foo");
     return super.enhance(scaAccessToken, authentication);
  }
```

---

In my AuthotizationServerConfig I create this:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    ScaJwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new ScaJwtAccessTokenConverter();
    accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("familia-mgpe"); // Parte da string de validação do token JWT.
    return accessTokenConverter;
}
```